# Why are the <hr> tags not visible on the website?

Tags: html, css, web

The hr tags were perfectl fine and then out of no where it disappeared even though the tags are in the html code. Its like this for all of the pages but there arent any hr tag css codes in my dreamweaver template page. Below is the jsfiddle page code i was working on when this happenned.

```
<hr>

http://jsfiddle.net/DuDjK/1/
```

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/template.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>OBDKey</title>
<style type="text/css">
#footer {
    color: #5A87B4;
}
</style>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

    *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    }


#menubar * { padding: 0; margin: 2; }
        body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; width:100%; font-size:12px}
        #menubar ul{
text-align:center;
}
        #menubar ul li { display:inline-block; padding: 2px;  position: relative; margin-left:-10px; margin-right:-20px; margin:invisible; }
        #menubar ul a { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 80px; height: 30px; text-align:center; background: #FFF; color:#000; border-style: solid; border-width:2px; border-color:#1570a6; text-decoration: none; }
#menubar li:after{
     border-left:50px solid black;
   border-right:60px solid black;
   content:"";
   position:relative;
   left:-12px;
   top:-18px;  
   z-index:-1;
   display:block;
   height:1px;
}





#cssmenu {
    background: #E6E6E6;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li {
    font: 100% 'Helvetica', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
       list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
    background: #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
    background: #E6E6E6 url(images/menuhover.png) left center no-repeat;
    color: #1570A6;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}





    #header {
    text-align: center;
    background: #FFA500;
    height: inherit
    padding: 15px 0;
    border: 0;
    }

    #footer {
    background:#5A87B4;
    padding:20px 0;
    text-align:center;
    }


#footer {
    color: #5A87B4;
}
#footer {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.footertextsize {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.font-color {
    color: #5A87B4;
}
heading {
    color: #000;
}

#header #checkout p {
    color: #FFF;
}
</style>

<body>

<div id="header"  >
    <div id="checkout">
      <p align="right"><a href="Home.html"><img src="images/obdlogo.png" align="left" /></a></p>
  <p align="right"><strong><a href="Order%20Online.html">BUY </a></strong></p>
  <p align="right"><a href="Order%20Online.html"><strong>NOW</strong></a></p>
  <p align="right">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="right">&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <hr style="height:5px; background-color:#FFF; solid #FFF; border:0"  />
  <hr style="height:5px; background-color:#1570a6; solid #1570a6; broder:0"  />
  <hr style="height:5px; background-color:#FFF; solid #FFF; border:0"  />
  <hr style="height:5px; background-color:#1570a6; solid #1570a6; broder:0"  />
  <hr style="height:5px; background-color:#FFF; solid #FFF; border:0"  />
  <hr style="height:5px; background-color:#1570a6; solid #1570a6; broder:0"  />
</div>
<div id="menubar"> 
    <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="Software.html" ><strong>SOFTWARE</strong></a>
    </li>
      <li><a href="Products.html"><strong>PRODUCTS</strong></a></li>
    <li>
    <a href="FAQ.html"><strong>FAQ</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>




<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="EditRegion1" -->
<p><strong>Press Information, News and Reviews</strong></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color"><strong>January 2012: New OBDKey Interface Distributor for Germany, Austria and Switzerland</strong></p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color">From January 2012 OBDKey units are available to purchase from our new distributor for German speaking countries: <strong>Electronic-Fuchs</strong>.</p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color"><img src="images/Fuchs_Banner.jpg" width="296" height="77" alt="fuchs" longdesc="file:///C|/Users/Production/Desktop/Mobile Website/Mobile Website/images/Fuchs_Banner.jpg" /></p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<hr>
<p>
<p>
<p class="font-color"><strong>November 2011: OBDKey Recieves &quot;Recommended&quot; Award from Car Mechanics Magazine</strong></p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color"><img src="images/carmechmagrec.jpg" alt="carmechmagrec" width="120" height="128" longdesc="images/carmechmagrec.jpg" align="left" />&quot;The Bluetooth in the name gives it away - here's a package that means you don't have to be permanently connected to your car during diagnostics session. But, as handy as that is, the real bonus of the Bluetooth is that this package can be run on a plethora of mobile phones and personal organisers, instead of just a laptop.<img src="images/carmechmag.jpg" alt="carmechmag" width="100" height="139" longdesc="images/carmechmag.jpg" align="right" /></p>

<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color"><em>The bundled programme is businesslike, works works well and even goes beyond-OBD on VAG cars&quot;</em></p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color"><em><strong>&quot;Value for money 6/6&quot;</strong></em></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<hr />
<p>
<p>
<p class="font-color"><strong>September 2011: OBDKey WLAN Shipping in smaller Casing</strong>
<p class="font-color">
<p class="font-color">
<br />
<p class="font-color"><img src="images/obdkeywifism.jpg" alt="wlansm" width="112" height="88" longdesc="images/obdkeywifism.jpg" align="right" />
<p class="font-color">From September 2011 all OBDKey WLAN units will be shipped in the standard OBDKey case with dimensions 62x45x24 mm (65x45x24 mm including accessory loop).
<p class="font-color">
<p class="font-color">Approved for connection to wireless LAN devices and fully tested on OBD-II compatible vehicles and systems.
<p>
<br />
<p>
<p class="font-color"><strong><a href="obdkeywlanpressrelease.pdf">Press release</a></strong>
<p><br />
<p class="font-color"><strong><a href="WLAN.html">More information</a></strong>
<p class="font-color">
<p class="font-color">
<hr />
<p class="font-color"><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="font-color">&nbsp;</p>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us<strong></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="About%20Us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Support.html">Get Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p class="font-color"><br />
</p>

<div class="footertextsize" id="footer">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><strong><a href="http://www.obdkey.com">View Desktop Site</a></strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><strong>Copyright © Copyright (C) 2011 KBM Systems Ltd.</strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><strong>OBDKey is a registered  trademark of KBM Systems Ltd.</strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Copyright%20Notice.html">Copyright Notice </a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Comment: How about a link to your website/page where it is not displaying at?

Comment: its not published yet so i cant do that. Still under construction

Comment: In your JS fiddle, you put EVERYTHING in the CSS field. Correct that. put your HTML code in the box labeled HTML, etc.

Comment: ohhhhh. Sorry about that. Im new to that website. Ill fix that the next time but i got the solution to my problem from Lotus below :) Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of this universal selector, which selects every element:

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
```

This is simply removing the border from the `<hr>`

Comment: Yes it was the border. Thanks a lot mate